# How to view foxpro registries using php

Tags: php, html, database, dbf

could you please help me out?
I need to show a registry of a .dbf table in php and have the following code.

```
<html>
    <form method="get">
        <input type="text" name="nrdoc"></input>
        <input type="submit"></input>
    </form>

<?php
if(isset ($_GET['nrdoc'])){
$thefile = "winges/vcabdoc.DBF";
if($thefile){
include('./dbf_class.php');
$dbf = new dbf_class($thefile);
$num_rec=$dbf->dbf_num_rec;
$field_num=$dbf->dbf_num_field;
$endexct = $timer->end();

    echo("<blockquote>File Name : $thefile<br>Number of Records : $num_rec<br>Number of Fields : $field_num</blockquote>");
    echo('<table border=1 cellspacing=0>');
    echo('<tr>');
    echo('<td>No.&nbsp;</td>'); 

    for($j=0; $j<$field_num; $j++){
        echo '<td>&nbsp;'.$dbf->dbf_names[$j]['name'];
            if ($dbf->dbf_names[$j]['type']!='M') {
                echo '<br>Length='.$dbf->dbf_names[$j]['len'];
            }
        echo '<br>Type='.$dbf->dbf_names[$j]['type'].'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';


    $i=$_GET['nrdoc'];
        if ($row === $dbf->getRow("SELECT *, FROM winges/vcabdoc.dbf WHERE 'VCANUM' == $i")) {
            echo('<tr>');
            echo('<td align="right">'.str_pad($i+1, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT).'</td>');
                for($j=0; $j<$field_num; $j++){
                    if ($dbf->dbf_names[$j]['type']=='N') {
                        echo '<td align="right">';
                    } 
                    else {
                        echo '<td align="left">';
                    }
            echo htmlentities($row[$j]).'&nbsp;</td>';
            }
            echo '<tr>';
        }
}
    echo('</table>');
}
?>
</html>
```

The dbf_class.php is from [http://www.phpclasses.org](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1302-PHP-Extract-information-from-a-DBF-database-file.html#download)

And it always returns the first data line on the database, please help me.

Thanks in advance.

João

Comment: If the timer class has nothing to do with the question, then remove it and the references to it so the code is smaller. And clean the code a little...it's rather ugly.

Comment: You are including `dbf_class.php` - rather critical to the operation.  Where's that from?  [phpclasses.org](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1302-PHP-Extract-information-from-a-DBF-database-file.html)?

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention that, thank you for the reminder.

Comment: I don't know what you're doing with `$dbf->getRow(...)` that takes an integer record number, not faux-SQL, it's not LINQ.

Comment: I've been using it like this $dbf->getRow($i), but i changed it so you know what i'm trying to do, i know that doesn't work...

Comment: Please clarify a registry of a dbf file. Present the data from? the record count of all tables IN a directory of DBF files?  Are the .dbf files part of a database container (.DBC under VFP)? you SHOULD be able to just do a "select COUNT(*) from TableName" should be very quick.  I just simulated a table of 30 columns, 2 million records and got record count in 2.5 seconds.  So, I don't know how large your tables are, but you could also get max() of a PK too as basis of display...

Answer (score 1):

I found an easy way to extract data from .dbf using perl library [XBASE](http://www.adelton.com/perl/DBD-XBase/)
Using this library I wrote a small scripts which reads given file and outputs a json string.

```
# foxpro2json.pl
use File::Basename;
use XBase;
$filename=$ARGV[0]; 

my $table = new XBase $filename or die XBase->errstr;
my @fields = $table->field_names;
my $cursor = $table->prepare_select();
my $return = '';
my $i = 0;

while (my @row = $cursor->fetch) {
  $json = '{';
  $i = 0;
  foreach $val (@row) {
    $val =~ s/(['"\/\\])/\\$1/g;
    $json .= '"'.$fields[$i].'":"'.$val.'",';
    $i++;
  }
  $json  = substr($json, 0, -1);
  $json .= '},';
  $return .= $json;
}
$return  = substr($return, 0, -1);
print '['.$return.']';
```

This is how I call this file inside my php code:

```
exec('/usr/bin/perl /var/www/foxpro2json.pl /var/www/myfilename.dbf', $json);
$array = json_decode($json[0], true);
```